# Bootstrap 3 XS - Why threshold is high and how to change?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, less

I've used bootstrap for awhile now, and for the life of me I cannot remember the `xs` coming into play at `767px`. I'm using `Boostrap v3, LESS`, and cannot find where to change the threshold for the `hidden-xs` class. I did a project-wide search, and only the variables are popping up in the Find Results.

file: responsive-utilities.less

line: 134

```
.hidden-xs {
  @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
     .responsive-invisibility();
  }
}
```

When I inspect element in chrome the variable, `@screen-xs-max` is being set at `767px`

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
  .hidden-xs {
     display: none !important;
  }
```

I have `disable cache` on in chrome as well. I attempted to change the `@screen-xs-max` variable by removing the variable all together and putting a hard number, but that didn't change it either.

I've also looked at this website, [Customize and download Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints), and that confused me even more b/c I use `col-XXX-##` and `hidden-XX`, not the `@screen-xs`, which is in the `Media queries breakpoints` section. And not only that, but the `xs` is set to `480px`.

Appreciate it.

---

**Addition:**

I am compiling LESS using less.js as well.

Maybe my main question would be - how do I increase the `sm` threshold, and reduce the `xs` threshold - as in have the `xs` at a lower pixel setting, like `520px`?

Comment: Ignore `@screen-xs`. It's deprecated and only used in one place, in a hacky part of the navbar: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.2/less/navbar.less#L96

Answer (score 2):

If you are compiling the LESS yourself, and want to modify the breakpoint between `xs` and `sm` sizes, try changing the `@screen-sm` variable in the `variables.less` file.

e.g. for v3.3.0:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.0/less/variables.less#L285

Line 285

Comment: No go - stays the same, 767px    @screen-sm:  520px;  // changed to